# Why doesn't Steam start?

Tags: steam

When I try to start Steam nothing happens. Reinstall doesn't help.

```
$ steam
Running Steam on ubuntu 13.04 64-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1378500910_client)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1378500910_client)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1378500910_client)
unlinked 0 orphaned pipes
removing stale semaphore last operated on by process 7278 with name 0eBlobRegistryMutex_DC7EBB4AEA41D3C6C74E5EFFD6757CEC
removing stale semaphore last operated on by process 7278 with name 0eBlobRegistrySignal_DC7EBB4AEA41D3C6C74E5EFFD6757CEC
removing stale semaphore last operated on by process 7278 with name 0emSteamEngineInstance
removing stale semaphore last operated on by process 7278 with name 0eSteamEngineLock
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "overlay-scrollbar"
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1378500910_client)
[0913/182910:WARNING:proxy_service.cc(958)] PAC support disabled because there is no system implementation
```

How to fix it?

Comment: This: http://askubuntu.com/questions/345146/steam-stopped-running/345151#345151

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I was having the same problem. To solve it, just delete the `.steam/steam/appcache`
 directory. You can do this from the terminal:

```
rm -Rf ~/.steam/steam/appcache
```

You have to run this every time you want to start steam until Valve fix this problem.

Comment: You don't have to remove it manually everytime. Simply write a two line script that does it for you!

Comment: @tim I don't know why you should to make it everytime... isn't once just enough?

Comment: @Braiam every time steam starts afaik the appcache file will be created

Comment: This folder doesn't exist. Any suggestion for newer versions of Steam?

Answer (score 3):

It stopped working 4 hours ago for my part too.

I reinstalled steam even redownloaded dota2, and it still doesn't work.
I'm pretty sure that this is a steam related issue... and they will fix it pretty soon I guess.

For the time being, you can bypass this issue by removing `$HOME/.steam/steam/appcache`.

Answer (score 1):

For those who cannot solve this issue with the other suggestions on this page, you can go into `home/username/.steam/steam/SteamApps/common` and all of your game folders will be in there. In each game folder is an executable. Just find the executable and run it to bypass Steam.

Comment: Is this the same as searching for the game name on the Dash and then running it from there? Because I've noticed that procedure doesn't really bypass Steam, I can see it quickly starts  BigPicture Mode and then the game.

Comment: @WaldirLeoncio No, it is not the same.