# Steam stopped running

Tags: steam

5h ago steam was running well, but now there's an error occuring when i try to launch steam: `[0913/173803:WARNING:proxy_service.cc(958)] PAC support disabled because there is no system implementation`

I have my system upgraded.

Any ideas?