# Steam won't start,

Tags: steam

Steam was running fine for a few months, but recently it didn't start up, so I tried re-installing it and it still doesn't start!

Is it My PID and how do I check if My PID is running?

Comment: This: http://askubuntu.com/questions/345146/steam-stopped-running/345151#345151

Answer (score 0):

I just had a very similar problem with my steam. What i did to fix my problem was to go to System Monitor. And in the processes tab i found steam and ended the process.
Then i restarted my steam and everything worked fine.

I have no idea if this will work for you, but i hope it helps.

GL