# Steam not wanting to start on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: 16.04, 64-bit, games, steam

So I just got done with a fresh install of the latest Ubuntu version and steam was one of the first programs I installed. I used the `sudo apt-get steam` command in the terminal so all is done and good except Steam will not start after it goes though it's little update process. If I start it through the terminal with just 'steam' I get this:

```
ryan@Ubuntu:~$ steam
Running Steam on ubuntu 16.04 64-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
[2016-12-23 20:41:00] Startup - updater built Dec 20 2016 05:49:54
Looks like steam didn't shutdown cleanly, scheduling immediate update check
[2016-12-23 20:41:01] Checking for update on startup
[2016-12-23 20:41:01] Checking for available updates...
[2016-12-23 20:41:02] Download skipped: /client/steam_client_ubuntu12 version 1482202190, installed version 1482202190
[2016-12-23 20:41:02] Nothing to do
[2016-12-23 20:41:02] Verifying installation...
[2016-12-23 20:41:02] Performing checksum verification of executable files
[2016-12-23 20:41:07] Verification complete
ryan@Ubuntu:~$
```

I have been though several topics about Steam not running or working but none of the other issues seems to related to mine.

Most of the topics I have found are all similar to these:
[Why doesn't Steam start?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/345120/why-doesnt-steam-start)   Deleting Cache.
[Steam not opening in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/771032/steam-not-opening-in-ubuntu-16-04-lts) suggested a fix to remove a file to which my Terminal says this particular path does not exist or 'No such file in directory':

```
 rm ~/.steam/steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6^C
```

Comment: Steam has been under Denial of Service attack today... it's not you it's them.

Comment: Why don't you list some of the topics so a potential helper doesn't offer that help again.