# Kubuntu 18.04 Steam will not open

Tags: kubuntu, steam, 18.04

I just upgraded yesterday to Bionic Beaver and whenever I try to open up steam a window quickly pops up that says "verifying installation" and then nothing happens. Here's what I get when I try to open it from the terminal:

```
Running Steam on ubuntu 18.04 64-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
Pins up-to-date!
[2018-04-28 20:44:41] Startup - updater built Apr  2 2018 15:23:43
Looks like steam didn't shutdown cleanly, scheduling immediate update check
[2018-04-28 20:44:41] Checking for update on startup
[2018-04-28 20:44:41] Checking for available updates...
[2018-04-28 20:44:41] Download skipped: /client/steam_client_ubuntu12 version 1522709999, installed version 1522709999
[2018-04-28 20:44:41] Nothing to do
[2018-04-28 20:44:41] Verifying installation...
[2018-04-28 20:44:41] Performing checksum verification of executable files
[2018-04-28 20:44:42] Verification complete
```

I've already tried uninstalling and reinstalling, rebooting, and deleting the app cache like [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/345120/why-doesnt-steam-start) recommends.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77894/discussion-on-question-by-emandudeguy-kubuntu-18-04-steam-will-not-open).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue.  Steam worked after running:

```
sudo apt install libnvidia-gl-390:i386
```

Comment: Holy expletive! That actually works! You deserve a cookie :D